# Pivot columns to rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

So I currently have this data set & I need to transform it from the form shown in the first picture to what it looks like in picture two. I have tried using pivot_longer but I can't seem to get it to work...

[image: df1]

[image: df2]

Comment: why did you replaced data with pics?  posting of data in reproducible format is desirable

Comment: I started out using the GitHub-flavored markdown format in the preview it was fine but when I submitted the question it just ended up being a muddle of numbers, vertical bars & dashes. Apologises I know it's not the most helpful!

Comment: perhaps using pictures, got 2 downvotes in your account as well as one in mine.  :D  Nevertheless, if the problem is solved please accept the answer and don't forget to upvote it.  :)

Comment: moreover, for posting data here You can use R's `dput()` function.  Just paste the results of `dput(df[1:6,])` (e.g. if you want to post 6 rows of your data named `df`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have spaces in column names, so I am assuming there are underscores in place of spaces.

**Note: If you want to clean names of columns too, you can make use of janitor library** using `janitor::clean_names()`

```r
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = F)

df <- read.table(header = T, text = 'name   running_1st_half    running_2nd_half    sprinting_1st_half  sprinting_2nd_half
A   9091    10569   102 89
B   10020   12939   100 81
C   12031   11532   87  78
D   9878    8980    123 100
E   12209   12001   131 105
F   12333   11000   90  121')

df %>%
  pivot_longer(!name, names_pattern = '([^_]*)_(.*)', names_to = c('metric', '.value')) 
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    name  metric    `1st_half` `2nd_half`
#>    <chr> <chr>          <int>      <int>
#>  1 A     running         9091      10569
#>  2 A     sprinting        102         89
#>  3 B     running        10020      12939
#>  4 B     sprinting        100         81
#>  5 C     running        12031      11532
#>  6 C     sprinting         87         78
#>  7 D     running         9878       8980
#>  8 D     sprinting        123        100
#>  9 E     running        12209      12001
#> 10 E     sprinting        131        105
#> 11 F     running        12333      11000
#> 12 F     sprinting         90        121
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>